# Fixed point theorem on a compact set

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

LEt $X\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ be a closed set, and $f: X \to X$ be a function such that

$$ ||f(x_1) - f(x_2)|| < ||x_1 - x_2|| \; \; \forall x_1, x_2 \in X $$

If $X$ is compact, then there exists a unique $p \in X$ such that $f(p) = p $.

How Can I approach this problem? My thought was to assume by contradiction that $\forall x $, $f(x) \neq x$. But, then how can I obtain a contradiction?

Comment: Isn't your function a contraction on a complete space?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal No, it's what is sometimes known as a weak contraction. For Banach's fixed point theorem, you need a $q < 1$ with $\lVert f(x)-f(y)\rVert \leqslant q\cdot \lVert x-y\rVert$, here $$\sup_{x\neq y} \frac{\lVert f(x)-f(y)\rVert}{\lVert x-y\rVert} = 1$$ is possible. If a fixed point exists, it is of course unique, but a weak contraction on a complete metric space need not have a fixed point. You need compactness (or a stronger contraction property) to guarantee the existence of a fixed point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $x\mapsto \lVert x-f(x)\rVert$ is continuous. Since $X$ is compact, it attains its minimum, say in $x_0\in X$. What follows for $x_0$ and $f(x_0)$?

Comment: Then, uniqueness is pretty much a straightforward application of the assumptions.

Comment: Right. The uniqueness doesn't even need compactness.

Comment: That's a really nice way to do it. My first thought was to use Banach's fixed-point theorem (as I stated in my answer).

Comment: So, by compactness, then we have $\inf_{x \in X} g(x) = g(x_0) = ||x_0 - f(x_0)|| $ for some $x_0 \in X$. is this correct? @Daniel Fischer

Comment: @Learner Yes. And what follows for $g(f(x_0))$?

Comment: well, then $g(f(x_0)) = || f(x_0) - f(f(x_0))||$. uhmm I am kinda of stuck here. What should I do next? sorry for bothering you.

Comment: @Learner You have the premise that $\lVert f(x_1) - f(x_2)\rVert < \lVert x_1 - x_2\rVert$ for $x_1 \neq x_2$. Use that on $\lVert f(x_0) - f(f(x_0))\rVert$.

Comment: So, I end up having that $g(f(x_0)) \leq g(x_0) $. What can we conclude from this?

Comment: @Learner $g$ attains its minimum in $x_0$. If we had $x_0 \neq f(x_0)$, the premise would yield a strict inequality $g(f(x_0)) < g(x_0)$, so that can't be, hence $f(x_0) = x_0$.

Comment: why this stric inequality is not possible ?

Comment: @Learner Because then $g(x_0)$ wouldn't be a minimum.

Comment: what happens if $X$ is not compact? does the result still holds?

Comment: @Learner No, in that case, there is in general no fixed point under the hypotheses, consider $X = [1,\infty) \subset\mathbb{R}$ and $f(x) = x + 1/x$. Then $\lvert f(y) - f(x)\rvert = \lvert y-x\rvert\cdot \left(1 - \frac{1}{xy}\right) < \lvert y-x\rvert$ for $x\neq y$, but $f$ has no fixed point.